# Get oauth credentials!

Tags: testing, twitter

Do you know any online tool-website that generates the valid oauth credentials after login on twitter?

I need:

oauth_consumer_key, 
oauth_signature_method, 
oauth_token, 
oauth_timestamp, 
oauth_nonce, 
oauth_version, 
oauth_signature"

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter is the only source of valid OAuth tokens (for twitter), because you're effectively logging into twitter.

If you're looking for code to login/authenticate with twitter, check out http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries